# Why doesn't this for loop work and my variable equals to zero?

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, thanks in advance for answering me!

I need to count how many dots and exclamation marks there are in a single paragraph. I am using a for loop for this.

```
const storySigns = story.split('');
let puncCount = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < storySigns.length; i++)
     {
      if (i === '.' || i === '!') {
        puncCount += 1;
      }
    };
```

Why does the output of puncCount equals 0?

Comment: `i` is a number, not a dot or an exclamation mark. You need `storySigns[i]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I is a counter here its values is 0 then 1 then 2 then 3 until n
It will never be equal to '.' Or '!'